# Why can't I revert this change using Git?

Tags: git

I have a project using Spring Roo. Spring Roo changed some aj files. I tried to revert them through the git tortoise context menu, but it gives me an empty list to revert.

When I use

```
$git reset --hard
```

I still can't revert the changes.

```
c:\src\main\java\com\company\eorder\server\domain>git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../mockup/app/view/MyViewport.js
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../mockup/app/view/XXX_test_card.js
#       deleted:    ../../../../../../webapp/app/dao/RequisitionDataLocalStorageDAO.js
#       deleted:    ../../../../../../webapp/app/model/CCPhysician.js
#       deleted:    ../../../../../../webapp/app/model/ClinicalInfo.js
#       deleted:    ../../../../../../webapp/app/model/FileAttachment.js
#       deleted:    ../../../../../../webapp/app/model/Modality.js
#       deleted:    ../../../../../../webapp/app/model/Order.js
#       deleted:    ../../../../../../webapp/app/model/Patient.js
#       deleted:    ../../../../../../webapp/app/model/Physician.js
#       deleted:    ../../../../../../webapp/app/model/ReadingDoctor.js
#       deleted:    ../../../../../../webapp/app/model/RequisitionData.js
#       deleted:    ../../../../../../webapp/app/model/RequisitionTestForm.js
#       deleted:    ../../../../../../webapp/app/model/RequistionData_TMP.js
#       deleted:    ../../../../../../webapp/app/model/Specimen.js
#       deleted:    ../../../../../../webapp/app/model/Technologist.js
#       deleted:    ../../../../../../webapp/app/store/RequisitionLocalStorageStore.js
#       deleted:    ../../../../../../webapp/app/view/imaging_test_card.js
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/.classpath
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/.project
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/eOrder.roo
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/log.roo
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/pom.xml
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/java/com/company/eorder/server/domain/DiagnosticOrderLine.java
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/java/com/company/eorder/server/domain/DiagnosticOrderLine_Roo_JavaBean.aj
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/java/com/company/eorder/server/domain/Physician.java
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/java/com/company/eorder/server/domain/Physician_Roo_JavaBean.aj
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/java/com/company/eorder/server/domain/Requisition.java
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/java/com/company/eorder/server/domain/Requisition_Roo_JavaBean.aj
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/java/com/company/eorder/web/ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean_Roo_ConversionService.aj
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/java/com/company/eorder/web/RequisitionController_Roo_Controller.aj
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/database.properties
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/resources/log4j.properties
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/i18n/application.properties
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/codesystems/create.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/codesystems/list.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/codesystems/show.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/codesystems/update.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/diagnosticorderlines/create.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/diagnosticorderlines/list.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/diagnosticorderlines/show.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/diagnosticorderlines/update.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/footer.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/loincs/create.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/loincs/list.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/loincs/show.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/loincs/update.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/menu.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/orderlineparameters/create.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/orderlineparameters/list.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/orderlineparameters/show.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/orderlineparameters/update.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/orderlinesources/create.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/orderlinesources/list.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/orderlinesources/show.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/orderlinesources/update.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/orderspecimens/create.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/orderspecimens/list.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/orderspecimens/show.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/orderspecimens/update.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/patients/create.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/patients/list.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/patients/show.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/patients/update.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/physicians/create.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/physicians/list.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/physicians/show.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/physicians/update.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/requisitions/create.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/requisitions/list.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/requisitions/show.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/requisitions/update.jspx
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/test/java/com/company/eorder/server/domain/PhysicianDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj
#       modified:   ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/test/java/com/company/eorder/server/domain/RequisitionDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       ../../../../../../../../app_link.bat
#       ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/java/com/company/eorder/server/domain/RequisitionFormData.java
#       ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/java/com/company/eorder/server/domain/RequisitionFormData_Roo_Configurable.aj
#       ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/java/com/company/eorder/server/domain/RequisitionFormData_Roo_JavaBean.aj
#       ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/java/com/company/eorder/server/domain/RequisitionFormData_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord.aj
#       ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/java/com/company/eorder/server/domain/RequisitionFormData_Roo_Jpa_Entity.aj
#       ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/java/com/company/eorder/server/domain/RequisitionFormData_Roo_Json.aj
#       ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/java/com/company/eorder/server/domain/RequisitionFormData_Roo_ToString.aj
#       ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/java/com/company/eorder/web/RequisitionFormDataController.java
#       ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/java/com/company/eorder/web/RequisitionFormDataController_Roo_Controller.aj
#       ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/java/com/company/eorder/web/RequisitionFormDataController_Roo_Controller_Json.aj
#       ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/requisitionformdatas/
#       ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/test/java/com/company/eorder/server/domain/RequisitionFormDataDataOnDemand.java
#       ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/test/java/com/company/eorder/server/domain/RequisitionFormDataDataOnDemand_Roo_Configurable.aj
#       ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/test/java/com/company/eorder/server/domain/RequisitionFormDataDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj
#       ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/test/java/com/company/eorder/server/domain/RequisitionFormDataIntegrationTest.java
#       ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/test/java/com/company/eorder/server/domain/RequisitionFormDataIntegrationTest_Roo_Configurable.aj
#       ../../../../../../../../../src2/src/test/java/com/company/eorder/server/domain/RequisitionFormDataIntegrationTest_Roo_IntegrationTest.aj
#       ../../../../../../../../../src2/target/
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: What does `git status` show?

Comment: `git reset --hard` will reset your current files to the current branch, in other words, it will only remove what 'git status' shows you.  Do you want to revert to a particular commit instead, or to back out a particular commit?

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD` maybe?

Comment: I want to revert to the latest version in remote repository. I am new to git and used to use subversion, not quite understand the local repository. what happening on it according to the status above? I didn't commit the files and how come I can't "revert" as subversion does allow to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `git checkout <file>` to reset the file's changes that haven't been staged.

If there is ambiguity between a branch, add `--` before the filename.